# PYTHON (Controls & conditional flow)

Tags: python, controls, conditional-statements, control-flow

```
# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus():
    if ______:    # Start coding here!
        # Don't forget to indent
        # the code inside this block!
    elif _____
        # Keep going here.
        # You'll want to add the else statement, too!
```

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried?

Comment: Start by asking a real question.

Comment: Beautiful. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the tutorial from codecademy. The Instructions are:

Write an if statement in the_flying_circus(). It must include:

1. if, elif, and else statements;
2. At least one of and, or, or not;
3. A comparator (==, !=, <, <=, >, or >=);
4. Finally, the_flying_circus() must return True when evaluated.
   Don't forget to include a : after your if statements!

So you have to fill the underlined parts with comparison like 34 > 33. And use the comparators, which are asked. Your function should always return True so write a comparison like 1 > 0 in the if or in the elif statements, which is always true. But maybe you stuck somewhere else or forgot a colon.
Hope i could help you. Otherwise explain where you stuck.

Comment: Many thanks Ideuns. You are on point. New to python. I have sorted myself

Comment: you are welcome. :) If u have other questions check out the Q&A Forum from Codecademy first. When i was doing the tutorial python, it helped me.